# SonarQube Fetching analysis configuration settings shows the Operation has timed out

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to integrate SonarQube with Jenkins Job and docker. For fetching the analysis configuration it shows Operation timed out while accessing the sonar server. Tried to curl the same url in job and it is giving success response. Please find below logs:

```
14:14:36 c:\workspace\testProject\sonartest>curl "https://sonar.xxx.com/api/server/version" 
14:14:36   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
14:14:36                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
14:14:36 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    11  100    11    0     0     11      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    11
14:14:37 7.9.1.27448
14:14:37 c:\workspace\testProject\sonartest>"c:\workspace\testProject\sonartest\sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /k:"testprojectkey" 
14:14:39 SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.10
14:14:39 Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
14:14:39 Pre-processing started.
14:14:39 Preparing working directories...
14:14:40 09:41:33.668  Updating build integration targets...
14:14:40 09:41:33.713  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
14:16:21 09:43:15.17  Failed to request and parse 'https://sonar.xxx.com/api/server/version': The operation has timed out
14:16:22 
14:16:22 Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
14:16:22    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
14:16:22    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<DownloadServerVersion>b__0()
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.DoLogExceptions[T](Func`1 op, String url, Action`1 onError)
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.DownloadServerVersion()
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetServerVersion()
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetProperties(String projectKey, String projectBranch)
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.FetchArgumentsAndRulesets(ISonarQubeServer server, ProcessedArgs args, TeamBuildSettings settings, IDictionary`2& serverSettings, List`1& analyzersSettings)
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs localSettings)
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.PreProcess()
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.Execute()
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
14:16:22    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Main(String[] args)14:17:11 
14:17:11 c:\workspace\testProject\sonartest>exit 255
```

Comment: Hope this will help you https://community.sonarsource.com/t/help-with-time-outs/17629

Comment: Tried the mentioned suggestion of using http with ip address. Still facing the same issue